# Can I add multiple statements or multiple effects with azure policies?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I need to create an Azure policy for adding tags to resources which are being created without tags (eg name, support, costcenter)

The issue is that if for example I create a VM and I add Name tag, but I forget support and costcenter I want that my policy adds this two and keep my Name value tag.

Can I add some condition to modify effect? Or multiples if/then objects in the definition?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multiple `if/then` blocks are available as per Azure Policy schema [here][1]. Also here's the doc page demonstrates the [policy definition structure][1].

However, in your case, you don't need this, you might only need extra operations inside the []operations.

```
"then": {
  "effect": "modify",
  "details": {
    "roleDefinitionIds": [
      "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
    ],
  "operations": [
    {
      "operation": "Add",
      "field": "tags['costcenter']",
      "value": "US123"
    },
    {
      "operation": "Add",
      "field": "tags['Support']",
      "value": "Operations"
    }
  ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can add multiples conditional statements.

More information about [Combining Logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-logical-operators#sample-3-combining-logical-operators)

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Audit Azure Spring Cloud instances where distributed tracing is not enabled",
        "description": "Distributed tracing tools in Azure Spring Cloud allow debugging and monitoring the complex interconnections between microservices in an application. Distributed tracing tools should be enabled and in a healthy state.",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [{
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.AppPlatform/Spring"
                    },
                    {
                        "anyOf": [{
                                "field": "Microsoft.AppPlatform/Spring/trace.enabled",
                                "notEquals": "true"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.AppPlatform/Spring/trace.state",
                                "notEquals": "Succeeded"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "audit"
            }
        }
    }
}
```